# Unable to edit a question

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, edits

I have tried to edit this question thrice : [jQuery: show only one item per click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041576/jquery-show-only-one-item-per-click)

[image]

But after clicking on "Save Edits" it just redirects me back to question without the edits applied:

[image]

Why is this happening?

**Edit:** ***Just got a notification that the edit was successful. How? I never got the "Waiting for peer-review message"!***

[image]

Comment: There's an exception being thrown that we apparently don't surface as an error message. Even better, the exception doesn't make sense. (It's saying you're attempting to submit a edit while there's a suggested edit awaiting approval, but I don't see one in the UI.) Gonna dig a bit deeper in a bit here.

Comment: @AdamLear Yes, but when that happens it usually stops me from going to the *edit* page and displays a message.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's why this is probably a bug. :)

Comment: @AdamLear And now my edit just got applied. *Edit Bug* .

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but about 40minutes ago I was unable to delete my own answer - it was casting delete votes instead (I believe it got up to 3 votes from myself before it was removed). Perhaps the same issue is here: the pending edit is their own

Comment: @Rob Which answer?

Comment: @AdamLear http://stackoverflow.com/a/37041601/563532

Comment: @Rob Yeah, looks like that was also timing out on SQL stuff. We had a number of timeouts around 40 minutes ago. Looks like things are good now, but I'll ask around tomorrow to see what happened.

Comment: @AniMenon Re: your edit... see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

There's still a bit of a mystery here as to what exactly failed, but the gist of the problem was that when you submit a suggested edit, we also create a review task for the Suggested Edits queue. That bit timed out on SQL insertion, and it looks like that caused a bit of a chain reaction where you edit was submitted but nothing really knew about it... except for the bit that checks for existing pending edits on submission of another one.

I manually inserted the review task and approved it, so things should be in a reasonably good state now. I'll make myself a note to look into failure scenarios here to make sure that failures in the middle of the submission process don't end up in similarly weird states in the future (if possible).

Comment: Oh, [SQL timeouts](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhNqHajcRvo2nwA71zEfpQlai3htDW6aJ3Dz7l7QIVCTTd-3X0). Anyway thanx for the fix :)